# Equivalent tool of Kvaser Database Editor on Linux

Tags: linux, can-bus

What's a Equivalent tool of Kvaser Database Editor on Linux?

The only GUI tool I found is SavvyCAN and Wireshark CAN plugin. But both tools are for viewing logged data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pfrO.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmSNA.jpg)

I can't see the structure of the DBC files. Any help on that?

Comment: What makes you think there exists one for Linux? There's some open source project called "CAN Matrix" ([Github](https://github.com/ebroecker/canmatrix)) but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see/edit the DBC structure in SavvyCAN under File >> DBC File Manager. Select your DBC and click 'Edit'. You'll the see a tree structure with all ECUs, messages and signals. If you click on a signal, you'll see the structure of you message and all signals parameter (offset, factor, min/max...):

[image]